# Problem with keyboard after reinstall 'ubuntu-desktop'?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, layout

Before I couldn't login, it was showing:

> failed to start session

After I reinstalled `ubuntu-desktop`,  my keyboard settings is broken. Auto-switch layout keyboard don't work.

When I change the window, language switchs to default (i. e. eng). Now this 'feature' does not work and it is really necessary to me.

Keyboard setting: Allow different sources for each window -> Now window use the default source (I can't upload images).

Comment: Have the same problem with  my Ubuntu 14.04.3

Comment: If this seems to be a bug, please create a bug report.

Comment: What is your ubuntu version? Sometimes dbus is the problem and the language indicator.

Comment: In what manner exactly is the keyboard setting broken? Can you please provide a little more detail? What's the output of `setxkbmap -print`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster `xkb_keymap {
 xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
 xkb_types     { include "complete" };
 xkb_compat    { include "complete+ledscroll(group_lock)" };
 xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
 xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
` I still have the same problem in Ubuntu 14.04.4, Is there any solution?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: Can you please also include the output of `setxkbmap -query`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the 'Langauage Support' and 'Apply Systemwide' your language.

Comment: Your answer is missing any context. Please add more details and elaborate your answer so that even new users can understand what you mean without having to know the System Settings by heart.